# WKWebView requires delay to set its scrollView's contentOffset and zoomScale after load()

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I wrote some code to save off a WKWebView's scroll view's `contentOffset` and `zoomScale`, so they could be restored after the webView loads. I've found that setting those scrollView properties only works using a delay (e.g. with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()`. Why is this necessary? Is there a better way to achieve this?

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
    var zoomScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let wv = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        wv.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        wv.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        wv.navigationDelegate = self
        return wv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        reload()
    }

    @IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        reload()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // Without some delay, the restoration doesn't happen!
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25, execute: {
            self.webView.scrollView.setZoomScale(self.zoomScale, animated: false)
            self.webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(self.contentOffset, animated: false)
        })
    }

    private func reload() {
        contentOffset = webView.scrollView.contentOffset
        zoomScale = webView.scrollView.zoomScale;
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
    }
}
```

**Update with AJ B suggestion**
(Sorry for the repetition)

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private static let keyPath = "webView.scrollView.contentSize"
    private static var kvoContext = 0

    private var contentOffset: CGPoint?
    private var zoomScale: CGFloat?
    private var lastContentSize: CGSize?
    private var repeatedSizeCount = 0

    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let wv = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        wv.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        wv.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        return wv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: ViewController.keyPath, options: .new, context: &ViewController.kvoContext)
        reload()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: ViewController.keyPath)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard let newSize = change?[.newKey] as? CGSize, context == &ViewController.kvoContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }

        print("Observed: \(NSStringFromCGSize(newSize))")

        // Nothing to restore if these are nil
        guard let offset = contentOffset, let zoom = zoomScale else { return }

        guard let lastSize = lastContentSize, lastSize == newSize else {
            print("Waiting for size to settle")
            lastContentSize = newSize
            return
        }

        repeatedSizeCount += 1

        guard repeatedSizeCount >= 4 else {
            print("Size repeated \(repeatedSizeCount) time(s)")
            return
        }

        print("Settled - set saved zoom and offset")
        contentOffset = nil
        zoomScale = nil
        lastContentSize = nil
        repeatedSizeCount = 0
        webView.scrollView.setZoomScale(zoom, animated: false)
        webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
    }

    @IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        contentOffset = webView.scrollView.contentOffset
        zoomScale = webView.scrollView.zoomScale;
        reload()
    }

    private func reload() {
        print("Reload: \(NSStringFromCGSize(webView.scrollView.contentSize))")
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
    }
}
```

Prints the following:

```
Reload: {781, 1453}
Observed: {781, 1453}
Waiting for size to settle
Observed: {320, 595}
Waiting for size to settle
Observed: {320, 595}
Size repeated 1 time(s)
Observed: {320, 595}
Size repeated 2 time(s)
Observed: {320, 595}
Size repeated 3 time(s)
Observed: {320, 595}
Settled - set saved zoom and offset
Observed: {781, 1453}
Observed: {781, 1453}
Observed: {781, 1453}
```

Comment: UIWebView used to do the same thing. I submitted it as a bug report years ago, and Apple closed it as "behaves correctly." But then it got fixed in iOS 9. However, the issue remains in WKWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing something similar trying to get the content height after load and then sizing the webview's container to be that height. I struggled with it for awhile, the best approach I found was to observe the WKWebView's ScrollView content height, and when the content height repeats itself at the same size then you know it is completely loaded. This is a bit hacky but it worked consistently for me. I'd like to know if anyone knows a better solution as well.

```
//This was an example html string that would demonstrate the issue

var html = "<html><body><p>We're no strangers to love  You know the rules and so do I  A full commitment's what I'm thinking of  You wouldn't get this from any other guy    I just want to tell you how I'm feeling  Gotta make you understand    Never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down  Never gonna run around and desert you  Never gonna make you cry, never gonna say goodbye  Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you    We've known each other for so long  Your heart's been aching but you're too shy to say it  Inside we both know what's been going on  We know the game and we're gonna play it    And if you ask me how I'm feeling  Don't tell me you're too blind to see    Never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down  Never gonna run around and desert you  Never gonna make you cry, never gonna say goodbye  Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you    Never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down  Never gonna run around and desert you  Never gonna make you cry, never gonna say goodbye  Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you    We've known each other for so long  Your heart's been aching but you're too shy to say it  Inside we both know what's been going on  We know the game and we're gonna play it    I just want to tell you how I'm feeling  Gotta make you understand    Never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down  Never gonna run around and desert you  Never gonna make you cry, never gonna say goodbye  Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you</p><p><img src=\"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/maxresdefault.jpg\" width=\"\" height=\"\" style=\"display:block;height:auto;max-width:100%;width:100%;\"></p></body></html>"
```

I Injected some javascript to send events for the ready state and dom loading, and printed the size at those times as well as the didFinish navigation function. This was what printed:

```
// Adjusting the container height in didFinish navigation function 

started navigation
committed navigation
content height = 0.0
Javascript: Ready state change interactive | content height = 0.0
Javascript: DOM content loaded | content height = 0.0
Javascript: Ready state change complete | content height = 0.0
ended navigation content height = 0.0 (didFinish navigation)
content size observed = 1638.0
height constraint = Optional(0.0)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(0.0)
content size observed = 1171.0
height constraint = Optional(0.0)
content size observed = 2772.0
height constraint = Optional(0.0)
content size observed = 2772.0
height constraint = Optional(0.0)
content size observed = 2772.0
height constraint = Optional(0.0)
content size observed = 2772.0
height constraint = Optional(0.0)
content size observed = 2772.0
height constraint = Optional(0.0)
content size observed = 2772.0
height constraint = Optional(0.0)
content size observed = 2772.0
height constraint = Optional(0.0)

// Adjusting the container height after content size repeats itself KVO

started navigation
committed navigation
content height = 0.0
Javascript: Ready state change interactive | content height = 0.0
Javascript: DOM content loaded | content height = 0.0
Javascript: Ready state change complete | content height = 0.0
ended navigation content height = 0.0 (didFinish navigation)
content size observed = 1638.0
height constraint = Optional(1.0)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(1.0)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(1.0)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(691.666666666667)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(691.666666666667)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(691.666666666667)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(691.666666666667)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(691.666666666667)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(691.666666666667)
content size observed = 691.666666666667
height constraint = Optional(691.666666666667)
```

Comment: Are you saying the delay may be necessary because the webView isn't completely loaded when `didFinish...` is called? And you used the scrollView's height reaching the height it would be after loading (but before zooming in) to know that it was fully loaded?

Comment: Yeah the web view is loaded but the scrollview hasn't finished laying out. What I found was that the web content would load, the 'didFinish' function would fire, and I'd adjust the size of the web view container. However setting the height at this point would screw up how the web view content would lay out, it would add a huge amount of whitespace for some reason. So I set a delay, but depending on the device and connection speed it would only work sometimes. But using KVO on the scrollview's content size, and waiting for it to reach a consistent size would work

Comment: How many KVO changes did you observe (no pun intended) before you deemed the scrollView done changing? I tried resetting offset and zoom after I see the same size two times via KVO, but then after I change it I see two more KVO callbacks at the original, non-zoomed size. If I omit resetting offset and zoom, I see a total of five KVO callbacks at the original size.

Comment: I didn't observe a set amount of times, I just disabled any user interaction on the webview until I observed the same size twice (any movement, zoom, etc will fire the contentSize KVO and can make you think it is loaded prematurely). I don't particularly like doing it this way, I was kind of hoping someone else would chime in with a better way of doing it. But is it working for you?

Comment: Observing the same size twice wasn't working, because after two I'd set zoom and offset, then I'd see KVO for that change, then I'd see KVO for two more changes, but at the original size observed in the first two KVOs. I'm not yet convinced I'm not doing something else wrong though.

Comment: Could you show me what your updated code looks like?

Answer (score 1):

I found that, at least for the content offset, I was able to set it in `webView(_, didFinish:)` without delay by setting it via JavaScript.

In other words, replace

```
self.webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(self.contentOffset, animated: false)
```

with

```
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollTo(\(self.contentOffset.minX), \(self.contentOffset.minY));)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//default flag is 2
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"scrollView:%.f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    self.flag--;
    if (self.flag == 0) {
        [self jump];
    }
}
- (void)jump{
    if ([self.urlString isEqualToString:self.webView.URL.absoluteString]) {
        CGFloat offsetY = 0;
        offsetY = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"history"];
        if (offsetY) {
            self.markLabel.hidden = NO;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, offsetY)];
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Although this may provide answer, it is often better to write how it solves the problem and how is it different from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I set two parameters `minimumZoomScale` and `setZoomScale` on `didFinish`

```swift
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = self.store.zoom
        self.scrollView.setZoomScale(self.store.zoom, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the reasons they mention above and which is that things are still going on in the Scrollview AFTER didFinish is called. I am still seeing this issue in iOS 13.